# Implementing a simple java TCP server

Tags: java, multithreading, serversocket, tcp

There are two readers plugged to the internal network. They just send data to the server machine, where I want to have this java app running receiving the data. It won't be that much data. Each reader could be transmitting single strings like "1234567" to a rate as much as maybe half a dozen times per second.

Without entering into much detail about the readers, they are datalogic and both are different models, but with this in common: They are configured to transmit the data via tcp/ip to a certain ip:port.

I tested the data trasmission with this software: https://www.hw-group.com//products/hercules/index_en.html to see if I'm receiving the data properly and it does check out, it works well.

The problem comes when I run my TCP server implementation: I receive the data from one of the devices 100% of the times, while the other one is hit and miss: Sometimes the data sent over the network never makes it to my app and I don't know why.

I'm pasting the code of what I'm using: It's simple but, with my java knowledge and after digging around the internet, it's the best I came up with.

Here's the java file with the main:

```
package tcpserverclasstest;

public class TCPServerClassTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    TCPServerThread myTCPServerThread = new TCPServerThread();
    myTCPServerThread.start();
    }
}
```

Here's TCPServer.java:

```
package tcpserverclasstest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;



import java.io.*; 



public class TCPServer extends Thread { 
    public static final int PORT_NUMBER = 4413;

    protected Socket socket;

    public TCPServer(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        System.out.println("New client connected from " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
        start();
    }

    public void run() {
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = socket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String request;
            request = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received:" + request);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to get streams from client");
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
                socket.close();
                System.out.println("Socket closed");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

And here's TCPServerThread.java:

```
package tcpserverclasstest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TCPServerThread extends Thread { 
    public static final int PORT_NUMBER = 4413;

    protected Socket socket;



    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Waiting for incoming connections on port " + PORT_NUMBER);
        ServerSocket server = null;
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER);
            server.setReceiveBufferSize(262144);
            server.setReuseAddress(true);
            while (true) {
                new TCPServer(server.accept());
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to start server.");
        } finally {
            try {
                if (server != null)
                    server.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to implement the server on a thread since I want to implement this into a bigger project in the future and I don't want that app locked in the loop that is waiting for connections.

Any clues on what should I do to see why I'm not receiving some of the data? Any suggestion on a better way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't ignore exceptions. `System.out.println("Unable to get streams from client");` doesn't tell you anything about the exception that occurred. At the very least, print the stacktrace, so you know that something went wrong and what it was. If you change that, do you see any exceptions printed?

Comment: Nope, I never get any exception, not even that vague message. :(

Answer (score 0):

first thing that comes to mind is your server only connects to one of the clients. Your TCPServerThread's run method listens for one connection and when it is made it initializes a TCPServer with this connection, meaning only one of the readers connects. Maybe after connecting to one reader you can listen for other.

Second, your TCPServer reads only one line and then closes the connection, and  a line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed. So your readers should send linefeed ('\n', or '\r', or '\r\n'). If not you shouldn't use readLine, maybe read some amount of data in a while loop.

To debug your TCP connections and really be sure the data is actually coming to your server, you can use [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/). This shows all the packets coming in your network card and you can filter based on tcp.port to see only your connections.